# Security Features in Android

Tags: android, security

I want to learn the (maximum) security features in android.

Whatever security feature may be.

Can you please guide me for that ?

If you know security features please list it here. So that i can learn it very well.

So far i have gone through :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html

http://www.androidauthority.com/

Thanks,
Kartik

Comment: This question lacks focus,  and there for you will not obtain a solid answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few other things:

- [Market licensing (LVL)](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html)
- Obfuscation ([ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/))
- Encryption and hashing using [MessageDigest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) (SHA or MD5)
- [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could always look into the OWASP Mobile Security Testing Guide as a starting point: https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg